# QT3D with C ++ and rotation

Tags: c++, rotation, qt3d

I hope someone can help me with this problem. I am new to working with QT3D and I need to make a Qt3D application using QT C++ for a task, the problem I have is that I need to rotate the figure from a specific point but it always rotates from the center point. How can I specify that the rotation is made from one of the pivots in the figure? I need it to be able to simulate the movement of a pendulum. Please help someone who tells me how I can solve this problem, here is my code.

```
void window::paint(){
    arm1 = new Qt3DExtras::QCylinderMesh();
    arm1->setRadius(0.5);
    arm1->setLength(3);

    arm1Transform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
    arm1Transform->setTranslation(QVector3D(-3, 3, 0));
    arm1Transform->setScale(1.5f);

    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *arm1Material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
    arm1Material->setDiffuse(Qt::red);

    arm1Entity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    arm1Entity->addComponent(arm1);
    arm1Entity->addComponent(arm1Material);
    arm1Entity->addComponent(arm1Transform);
}

void window::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    arm1Transform->setRotation(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), angle++));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You set the translate in your transform. It seems like Qt3D first applies the translation and then the rotation. Try the rotation without the translation that should work. I don't know how to apply the rotation and then the translation though.

Comment: the `arm1Transform->setTranslation(QVector3D(-3, 3, 0));` statement is to tell where the object will initially be placed. It is then, at the click of a button, that the rotation is performed.
So there is no function to rotate given a specific point. The way you tell me I would have to calculate the positions for the translation after rotating.

Answer (score 0):

You can make **arm1Entity** to be a child of a new QEntity. This new QEntity will be positioned at the point where you want to rotate from. So if you rotate the new QEntity, his child **arm1Entity** will rotate from the new QEntity's position.

EDIT code (not tested):

```
void window::paint(){
    arm1PivotEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    arm1PivotTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(arm1PivotEntity);
    arm1PivotTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(/*desired pivot position*/));
    arm1PivotEntity->addComponent(arm1PivotTransform);

    arm1 = new Qt3DExtras::QCylinderMesh();
    arm1->setRadius(0.5);
    arm1->setLength(3);

    arm1Transform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
    // as arm1 is now child of arm1 pivot, you need to set the relative position
    arm1Transform->setTranslation(QVector3D(/*relative position to arm1pivot position*/)); 
    arm1Transform->setScale(1.5f);

    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *arm1Material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
    arm1Material->setDiffuse(Qt::red);

    // made arm1 child of arm1pivot so it will inherits its rotation
    arm1Entity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(arm1PivotEntity); 
    arm1Entity->addComponent(arm1);
    arm1Entity->addComponent(arm1Material);
    arm1Entity->addComponent(arm1Transform);
}

void window::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    arm1PivotTransform->setRotation(angle++));
}
```